# Using map function to reformat array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need some help reformatting the structure of an object.

I am getting an array of objects from an API and I then need those specifically formatted.

Here is an example of two objects in the array that I receive. In this example, they are identical.

```
[

    {
        "parent": {
            "id": 0,
            "recnum": 5030000000,
            "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
            "location": null,
            "controlType": 0,
            "warehouse": null,
            "stkitm": false,
            "qtyohn": -271,
            "prtcst": 0,
            "avgcst": 0,
            "printed": 0,
            "preexisting": false
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "number": "101",
                    "description": "Lot 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Lot 1"
                },
                "controlType": 1,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -201,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "number": "201",
                    "description": "Serial 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Serial 1"
                },
                "controlType": 2,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -70,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            }
        ],
        "nulled": null
    },
    {
        "parent": {
            "id": 0,
            "recnum": 5030000000,
            "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
            "location": null,
            "controlType": 0,
            "warehouse": null,
            "stkitm": false,
            "qtyohn": -271,
            "prtcst": 0,
            "avgcst": 0,
            "printed": 0,
            "preexisting": false
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "number": "101",
                    "description": "Lot 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Lot 1"
                },
                "controlType": 1,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -201,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "number": "201",
                    "description": "Serial 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Serial 1"
                },
                "controlType": 2,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -70,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            }
        ],
        "nulled": null
    }


]
```

However, I only need certain keys from these objects printed out in another array of objects. like this:

```
[
    //PARENT
    {
       recNum: parent.recnum,
       prtNme: parent.prtnme,
       date: '',
       locNum: '',
       locDescription: '',
       lotSerNum: '',
       byTrans: '',
       running: parent.qtyohn,
       unitCost: '',
       extCost: ''
    },
    //CHILDREN
    { 
       recNum: '',
       prtNme: '',
       date: '',
       locNum: children[].location.number,
       locDescription: children[].location.description,
       lotSerNum: '',
       byTrans: '',
       running: children[].qtyohn,
       unitCost: '',
       extCost: ''
    }
]
```

The keys with empty strings may or may not be filled in with data later, but they need to be in the end object result.

Each object in the original array has one parent and a random amount of children. I need to somehow loop through each object in the array and print out the parent and the children in order.

Thanks for any suggestions or help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: So for each child, you want an item?

Comment: Also, How do you differentiate between parent and child in the final result ?

Comment: @HarisBouchlis I have tried using forEach, but it was messy and I didn't get very far.

Comment: @mstephen19 for every parent and each of their children, I need an item.

Comment: why not use the `.map()` method

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I do not need to differentiate between parents and children.

Comment: @mstephen19 I have started to attempt to use ```map``` however I am having issues getting the data to format correctly because of the complexity of the reformatting.

Comment: So each array can have multiple children objects? Like if the parent has 3 children, the length of the array would be 4? Because 1 parent object, and 3 children?

Comment: @mstephen19 each object within the array has one parent and can have any amount of children. The main array has objects containing one parent object and an array of children objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce to create this structure:

```js
const apiData = [

    {
        "parent": {
            "id": 0,
            "recnum": 5030000000,
            "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
            "location": null,
            "controlType": 0,
            "warehouse": null,
            "stkitm": false,
            "qtyohn": -271,
            "prtcst": 0,
            "avgcst": 0,
            "printed": 0,
            "preexisting": false
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "number": "101",
                    "description": "Lot 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Lot 1"
                },
                "controlType": 1,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -201,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "number": "201",
                    "description": "Serial 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Serial 1"
                },
                "controlType": 2,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -70,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            }
        ],
        "nulled": null
    },
    {
        "parent": {
            "id": 0,
            "recnum": 5030000000,
            "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
            "location": null,
            "controlType": 0,
            "warehouse": null,
            "stkitm": false,
            "qtyohn": -271,
            "prtcst": 0,
            "avgcst": 0,
            "printed": 0,
            "preexisting": false
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "number": "101",
                    "description": "Lot 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Lot 1"
                },
                "controlType": 1,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -201,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "recnum": 5030000000,
                "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
                "location": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "number": "201",
                    "description": "Serial 1",
                    "active": true,
                    "descriptionScanner": "Serial 1"
                },
                "controlType": 2,
                "warehouse": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number": 100,
                    "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                    "nettable": true,
                    "active": true
                },
                "stkitm": true,
                "qtyohn": -70,
                "prtcst": 0,
                "avgcst": 0,
                "printed": 0,
                "preexisting": false
            }
        ],
        "nulled": null
    }


];
const flatApiData = apiData.reduce((list, obj) => [...list, obj.parent, ...obj.children], []);
console.log(flatApiData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [

  {
      "parent": {
          "id": 0,
          "recnum": 5030000000,
          "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
          "location": null,
          "controlType": 0,
          "warehouse": null,
          "stkitm": false,
          "qtyohn": -271,
          "prtcst": 0,
          "avgcst": 0,
          "printed": 0,
          "preexisting": false
      },
      "children": [
          {
              "id": 1,
              "recnum": 5030000000,
              "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
              "location": {
                  "id": 2,
                  "number": "101",
                  "description": "Lot 1",
                  "active": true,
                  "descriptionScanner": "Lot 1"
              },
              "controlType": 1,
              "warehouse": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "number": 100,
                  "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                  "nettable": true,
                  "active": true
              },
              "stkitm": true,
              "qtyohn": -201,
              "prtcst": 0,
              "avgcst": 0,
              "printed": 0,
              "preexisting": false
          },
          {
              "id": 3,
              "recnum": 5030000000,
              "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
              "location": {
                  "id": 4,
                  "number": "201",
                  "description": "Serial 1",
                  "active": true,
                  "descriptionScanner": "Serial 1"
              },
              "controlType": 2,
              "warehouse": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "number": 100,
                  "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                  "nettable": true,
                  "active": true
              },
              "stkitm": true,
              "qtyohn": -70,
              "prtcst": 0,
              "avgcst": 0,
              "printed": 0,
              "preexisting": false
          }
      ],
      "nulled": null
  },
  {
      "parent": {
          "id": 0,
          "recnum": 5030000000,
          "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
          "location": null,
          "controlType": 0,
          "warehouse": null,
          "stkitm": false,
          "qtyohn": -271,
          "prtcst": 0,
          "avgcst": 0,
          "printed": 0,
          "preexisting": false
      },
      "children": [
          {
              "id": 1,
              "recnum": 5030000000,
              "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
              "location": {
                  "id": 2,
                  "number": "101",
                  "description": "Lot 1",
                  "active": true,
                  "descriptionScanner": "Lot 1"
              },
              "controlType": 1,
              "warehouse": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "number": 100,
                  "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                  "nettable": true,
                  "active": true
              },
              "stkitm": true,
              "qtyohn": -201,
              "prtcst": 0,
              "avgcst": 0,
              "printed": 0,
              "preexisting": false
          },
          {
              "id": 3,
              "recnum": 5030000000,
              "prtnme": "Wheel Assembly with Bearings",
              "location": {
                  "id": 4,
                  "number": "201",
                  "description": "Serial 1",
                  "active": true,
                  "descriptionScanner": "Serial 1"
              },
              "controlType": 2,
              "warehouse": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "number": 100,
                  "description": "TechnoGuard 21456 Atlantic Blvd-1",
                  "nettable": true,
                  "active": true
              },
              "stkitm": true,
              "qtyohn": -70,
              "prtcst": 0,
              "avgcst": 0,
              "printed": 0,
              "preexisting": false
          }
      ],
      "nulled": null
  }


];

const newData = [];

data.forEach(
  (ele)=>{
    const {recnum,prtnme,qtyohn} = ele.parent;
    const {children} = ele;  
    newData.push(
      {
        recNum: recnum,
        prtNme: prtnme,
        date: '',
        locNum: '',
        locDescription: '',
        lotSerNum: '',
        byTrans: '',
        running: qtyohn,
        unitCost: '',
        extCost: ''
      }
    );
    children.forEach(
      (cele)=>{
        newData.push(
        {
          recNum: '',
          prtNme: '',
          date: '',
          locNum: cele.location.number,
          locDescription: cele.location.description,
          lotSerNum: '',
          byTrans: '',
          running: cele.qtyohn,
          unitCost: '',
          extCost: ''
        });
      }
    );

  }
);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Created new array of object as asked